# Check a sequence of integers to see if it is non-decreasing

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector, a very long vector composed of integers in MATLAB. My question is what is a fast efficient way to check to see if that vector is non-decreasing in MATLAB? The vector has a few thousand elements, all positive integers. The vector starts with some positive integer, repeats a few dozens times and then is supposed to increment by one and repeat. For example, the vector should look something like

```
a = [5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 11];
```

The problem is that we suspect that the counter may have screwed up occasionally so once in a while the counter decreases and then increases, something like

```
b = [5 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 9 10 11 10 10 11];
```

so first I need to see if the sequence is non-decreasing. Then if it ever does decrease, it would be nice to know all the indices where the sequence decreases like that. I could only think of using first differences and checking to see if all entries are either zero or one. Any other clever ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check whether the sequence is non-decreasing, you can use one of the following:

```
all(diff(b) >= 0)
~any(diff(b) < 0)
```

To find the specific positions where it decreases:

```
find(diff(b) < 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 5):

use `diff` and `any` :

```
 any(diff(b)<0)
```

this will return true (1) if the sequence is decreasing and false (0) for  non-decreasing.